# How to fix MEMP_SYS_TIMEOUT in sntp client on stm32

Tags: c, stm32, ntp, lwip

On an STM32H7, I run LwIP, to learn more about raw API (NOSYS = 1).
Now, UDP (and TCP) server and client work just fine.

I'm next setting up an NTP client.

I initialize it this way (in sntp_client.c):

```
#define SNTP_CONF_IPADDR0   185
#define SNTP_CONF_IPADDR1   255
#define SNTP_CONF_IPADDR2   55
#define SNTP_CONF_IPADDR3   20

sntp_setoperatingmode(SNTP_OPMODE_POLL);
sntp_setservername(0, (char*)"pool.ntp.org");
sntp_init();
```

After start, I get the error

```
Assertion "sys_timeout: timeout != NULL, pool MEMP_SYS_TIMEOUT is empty" 
failed at line 212 in 
..\..\..\Middlewares\Third_Party\LwIP\src\core\timeouts.c
```

In Wireshark, I see no NTP packages are traced.

In sntp_init, sntp_request(NULL); is called, after which the time-out shows up.

What do I need to check next?

My source is here, the important part in in sntp_client.c:
https://github.com/bkht/LAN8742A_KSZ8851SNL_LwIP

Comment: Solved: I added LWIP_SNTP to MEMP_NUM_SYS_TIMEOUT

Comment: do you mean like this?
```
#define MEMP_NUM_SYS_TIMEOUT LWIP_SNTP
```